# Combine IF function with OR function to allow multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

*I have been using **`=IF(L2="","Active",IF(K2<=I2,"On Time",IF(K2>I2,"Late")))`** which worked, but now I need to check multiple conditions on **`F`** column*

*I have tried **`OR`** function*

```
=IF(OR(F2="Scheduled",F2="3 Hours 30 Minutes",IF(L2="","Active",IF(K2<=I2,"On Time",IF(K2>I2,"Late")))),"Other")
```

*My Data*

[image]

*How do I check if only service = F2="Scheduled",F2="3 Hours 30 Minutes" or if L2 is empty else check if its Late or On Time?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this?

```
   =IF(OR(F2="Scheduled",F2="3 Hours 30 Minutes", L2=""),"Active",
        IF(K2<=I2, "On Time", IF(K2>I2, "Late","Other")))
```

But it can probably be simplified because the *"Other"* case seems impossible:

```
=IF(OR(F2="Scheduled",F2="3 Hours 30 Minutes", L2=""),"Active",
    IF(K2<=I2, "On Time", "Late"))
```

Comment: for some reason I'm getting `Formula typed contains an error` on both examples

Comment: @0m3r weird, both worked for me, which at least proves correct syntax. May be you didn't c/p correctly?

Comment: @0m3r the only thing I can think of is that it is type here as two lines, you need to edit some cell before pasting in. I tried the formulas with edge cases in the data, errors and NA's etc. it worked perfectly for me so I can't figure out what is going wrong on your side :(

Comment: I know, let me play with it and I will let you know- Thanks

Comment: @0m3r - FWIW - the formulas in the answer work for me.

Comment: @YowE3K I'm sure it does but for some reason is not working for me. :-(,  but your formula has worked perfect- if you want to post i will accept it...

Comment: @0m3r - I have posted a "community wiki" answer.  (It didn't feel right to post an answer under my own name which was based on information not clear from the question itself.)

Answer (score 3):

If I am interpreting the logic flow correctly,

```
=IF(OR(F2={"Scheduled", "3 Hours 30 Minutes"}, L2=""), "Active", IF(K2<=I2, "On Time", "Late"))
```

If F2 is *Scheduled* OR F2 is *3 Hours 30 Minutes* OR L2 is empty then **Active**.
If none of those conditions apply then look at the dates in I2 and K2. If K2 is earlier or the same as I2, **On Time** otherwise **Late**.

There is no *Other*.

[image]

For all intents and purposes, this formula is identical to the one posted earlier by [A.S.H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4926357/a-s-h).

Comment: Any guess why is it not working for OP ("formula contains an error")? This is somewhat weird.

Comment: No, I went through all of the comments, checked for `;` vs `,`, checked that the dates were right-aligned (true dates) in the image, etc. and could not find anything.

Comment: Well yours don't have an `error` now the output value is incorrect - since `L2` is not empty then it should be either Late or On Time, which in this case its on time<br> if `POD Time` is empty then the job is still active, if pod time has date and time then the job is complete so i would like to know if its on time or late,  now for the next day 17:00 service I don't care for it so the value can be anything - Thanks again guys Jeeped and @A.S.H

Comment: I have misunderstood '*service = F2="Scheduled",F2="3 Hours 30 Minutes" or if L2 is empty*'. I'm afraid I am at a loss as to the logic but it seems you may need either an AND(...) or split off the L2="" to another IF.

Comment: Thanks I will give it try-

Comment: @0m3r From what I understand of your " if POD Time is empty then the job is still active, if pod time has date and time then the job is complete so i would like to know if its on time or late, now for the next day 17:00 service I don't care for it so the value can be anything" comment, the formula would be `=IF(L2="","Active",IF(OR(F2="Scheduled",F2="3 Hours 30 Minutes"),IF(K2<=I2,"On time","Late"),"Other"))`.

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K - that is what I was trying to do, apologizes if I have not made it clear., Your formula has worked-

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the logic here. This is your most recent definition:-

> since L2 is not empty then it should be either Late or On Time, which
>   in this case its on time
>  if POD Time is empty then the job is
>   still active, if pod time has date and time then the job is complete
>   so i would like to know if its on time or late

The formula `=IF(L2,IF(K2<=I2, "On Time", "Late"),"Active")` meets these requirements. If any of the text in column F has a bearing on the above it isn't explained in your definition.

Comment: That is not much different the my fist furmula, remeber I also need to check `if = F2="Scheduled",F2="3 Hours 30 Minutes"`

Comment: Yes. I know you want to check that. But I don't know what should happen differently when one is found or the other.

Comment: I know, but I appreciate the help tho.. :-)

Comment: Funny guy, you are :-). You know that I don't know what you want and don't want to tell me. Won't be able to help much then. Right?

Comment: I meant to say thanks for trying to help but I assumed  you look at the comment under Jeeped then you know what I was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Based on information supplied in comments to another answer

> if POD Time is empty then the job is still active, if pod time has date and time then the job is complete so i would like to know if its on time or late, now for the next day 17:00 service I don't care for it so the value can be anything

I believe the formula you are after is:

```
=IF(L2="","Active",
          IF(OR(F2="Scheduled",F2="3 Hours 30 Minutes"),IF(K2<=I2,"On time",
                                                                  "Late"),
                                                        "Other"))
```